# After ten years, I'd like to change my field at 35

Tags: career-switch

I work since 10 years now for the automotive industry in the R&D field (Software Engineering). I recently changed to another Department (also R&D, also Software). In this new job, I realized that by working for 10 years in the same Department I lost the opportunity of learning some other technologies at a professional level (which is obviously normal). I guess realizing this now, opened my appetite for learning more and more things and I have spent a deal of time reading and self learning and I have also ramped up in my new position in very interesting things.

But there is one field to which I feel really attracted to and which requires me to study more because normally (for what I have read) in these fields, companies tend to hire more people with PhD levels mostly. I am 35 and I would love to make a PhD or at least a Master in Science, but I don't know if it is too late now for that. On the other hand, I don't know if I could take one of these specializations and simply try to change my career to that new field along with the bag of 10 years experience (experience is always good right?). I am afraid that at the end this would turn to be just a waste of effort, time and money.

Has anybody been in a similar situation? What did you do? What did work and what did not?

Thanks.

Comment: which field are you talking about data science?

Comment: You are never too old to get a masters or PHD. More mature students are often preferred by universities from what I have observed. I did my masters with a guy 10 years older than me, he just wanted a degree and a career change.

Answer (score 2):

> Has anybody been in a similar situation? What did you do? What did work and what did not?

Although career choice is most of the times off-topic here, and you shouldn't base such important personal decision on other people's opinion, what I can say is that maybe it is time to consider **doing some Internships on the career you would like to transition to**.

This may help you get some experience on that subject more easily than trying to land a higher-level/permanent position on that matter, thus helping you learn what you need plus gaining some work experience to include on your job hunting on that area.

It is true that experience is always positive. However, if you want to apply to a *completely* different career, then including unrelated experience in your Resume will not help you land those jobs. Anyways, those 10 years of experience *do* have weight on your applications, and they make you more fit than say, someone fresh out of college specialized on that subject but without work experience.

If you should or should not pursue a Masters or PhD. is completely up to you. It is true that getting any of those will *surely* be something positive, but don't assume that those companies *only* hire people with such degrees and experience (in other words, **try applying first before concluding that you need to get a new degree**).

You could also try to study and practice those new skills by your own on your spare time, or well take some on line courses (also good material to include on resumes). Whatever you do, consider making it step by step, so you can see if your improvement is enough for what you seek or if you really need to invest on stronger studies, or take bigger leaps on your career investment.

Comment: Don't meant to be negative, but would a company hire an older intern?

Comment: @FrankFYC you can't know if you don't apply, probably some will and others don't. I even recall one of your answers suggesting internships (which actually inspired me in a way here for that suggestion) as a way to start a career change, even though the OP then was not a "young boy". Point is, that this OP will never know if he doesn't apply. Valid concern what you say though, but not something that one should take as impossible to overcome. If that is not an option, then OP will know that getting another degree may be a better idea (but only after trying).

Comment: Noted. Although in the US age discrimination is illegal, so I am on the fence as for whether or not this would be the most effective method. Perhaps asking the hiring manager to confirm that age will not be a factor, this way OP can narrow down internships that are open to the idea.

Comment: @FrankFYC yes, seems to be an effective algorithm. We also don't know if OP is in US, but still is a valid algorithm to take

Comment: Thanks to both for your insight! I will get some specialization and from there I will try to start doing some networking as suggested in the answer below. I think it is not a bad approach and then I will see if a Master degree is really necessary. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

> But there is one field to which I feel really attracted to and which
>   requires me to study more because normally (for what I have read) in
>   these fields, companies tend to hire more people with PhD levels
>   mostly

Hiring Phd levels is not always possible for companies. So they might look for people with hands on experience. The key here is **to get started and showcase hands on experience in your profile**.

Take MOOC and build your portfolio around the topic. Taking MOOC is considered a little **investment in yourself** as compared to a Masters degree. After taking MOOC the best is to **build your curated github repository** to showcase your new skills.

You may ask - **But who would look into my profile**? The next step is key

**Build your network in your new field**

Getting hired through the HR is always a difficult task because they have their own keywords. Assuming you have built your profile. Visit **Meetup group on the chosen field**, Have a list of people whom you are interested and go build your network. Your network might help you with the next job, but you must choose to **give before you ask for help** or offer some means of help as a means of paying back. To name a few.

- Offer help in pet projects.
- Built a github repo together.
- Contribute to open source projects.

> I am afraid that at the end this would turn to be just a waste of effort, time and money.

At the worst case you might end up **learning new things**. Learning something is never a waste of your effort.

Pursuing a Phd or a Master's degree is often thought as the only solution, but I am sure they would **need people with passion** and who can **get things done**. You may position yourself as one of them. Good luck.

Personally I have been an R&D engineer and ended up in a different career doing the above. And it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It seems like a simple but good strategy. I have already started with an online specilization. We'll see how it takes off from  there. Regarding your question from above; this new field is in deed Data Science - specifically Machine Learning / Deep Learning are the trigger for this new desire.

Comment: @eindemwort - Good luck with it. Drop me a note if you need some help with data science.